# How to setup simple static server where path '/' points to index.html within dirrectory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

There might be a very simple solution to this question, but I am not able to find answer online and due to my practice with node I can't figure it out either.

I'm trying to set up a simple server.js file that listens on port 80 and serves `/dist/index.html` file when users enter root address, so `example.com`

This is my project structure

```
dist/
  index.html
  bundle.js
node-modules/
package.json
server.js
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a static server with [express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port: ' + 80);
});
```

You simply run `node server.js` to get the static server. This app can also be deployed.

Comment: I'm getting this error after running `node server.js` (named my file server.js), here is the error: `throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event`

Comment: What's the content of the `server.js` file?

Comment: Pasted it from your answer, turns out I can't specify port 80 on a local machine as it is in use, changing it to 8080 worked.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the error. Port `80` is always in use. I just translated your question (should have put in a PORT variable).

Answer (score 1):

[http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) is a simple method of serving from your file system. Install that, then just run `http-server -p X` in the command line in your project folder, substituting your port number for X

Comment: So simply running `http-server ./dist/index.html` will do the job?

Comment: No need for the file path, run the original command in my answer from inside the dist folder and then access the link you want - so for example; http-server -p 8080 will allow you to access http://localhost:8080/index.html